# Load The Javascript Of The Page While Loading The Page Itself With CasperJs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to submit a form. When I am using firefox the page will be loaded then I open the firebug I can see a input field named *"content_html"*  but when I go to check the source of the page from *"view page source"* I do not see the input field *"content_html"*. I checked further and found out there is a javascript which will be loaded in the browser to show that input field. The code is like

```
geteditorinit("http://example.com/pub","data[content_html]",298996,1,750,350,0,0,"content_html");
```

So I can conclude that *"content_html"* hidden input field will only be loaded after this javascript code is executed when I visit the page which contains this form. I need to assign some value to this input field to be able to submit the form. Since I cannot get the manipulated Javascript HTML ,like the one I get in the browser, with CasperJs I am not able to assign any value to it with CSS selector. Because the CSS selector does not find this hidden input field. How can I load the page with the javascript it contains so I can get HTML like firebug which shows the input field to me to be able to submit it?
After I login, I go to the page which contains the form  I want to be submitted like this

```
casper.thenOpen(POST_URL, function(){
          //Here I type the code to fill the form
});
```

**P.S. [ 1 ]** If  the PhantomJS is a full browser and I don't need to run Javascript then why I cannot fetch this hidden input field with CSS selector?
[image]
The above picture is taken from *Firebug*. As you see it shows the input field in colorless mode. I want to be able to select *"content1_html"* and set value to it then submit my form.
**P.S. [ 2 ]** I have found that when I load the posting page, it will separately make an ajax request to another page to autosave the content of the *"content1_html"*. I need to open the posting page, make a post request for *"content_html"* to another page, after that click the submit on the page I have already loaded. Can I make another tab or open another url without losing the data I already have? because after each refresh the form token would be changed and I will not be able to submit the post successfully.

Comment: To make it clear: 1. The form you're interested in is in an iframe? 2. Have you taken a screenshot to see whether the form is the? It's possible that you need to wait a little to ensure that the iframe is loaded.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I have edited the question. Indeed, there is an editor which would be called with javascript to show the input field so no iframe, however, If I am making mistake, I will add a picture of firebug in a moment.

Comment: PhantomJS is a full browser and should run all code by itself. There should be no need for you to run some function. Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I have updated the question with a better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to select that element. You can try for example the following CSS selectors and they would work depending on which elements are also on the page:

- `"input[name = 'data[content1_html]']"` based on exact name attribute match
- `"input[id ^= 'hdndata[content1_html]']"` based on beginning of id attribute

Now, to change the value, you need to use `casper.evaluate()`, because the DOM can only be accessed through this function and CasperJS doesn't provide any convenience functions for this case. It's sandboxed, so you need to explicitly pass the values in.

```
casper.evaluate(function(selector, value){
    document.querySelector(selector).value = value;
}, selector, value);
```

It may be necessary to wait until that input field is present in the page:

```
casper.waitForSelector(selector, function then(){
    this.evaluate(function(selector, value){
        document.querySelector(selector).value = value;
    }, selector, value);
    // Do something to submit the form
});
```

If it is enough to add this hidden input to the DOM before submitting the form, here is the code for this:

```
casper.evaluate(function(value){
    var parent = document.querySelectorAll(".rteDiv")[1];

    // get dynamic ID
    var id = parent.querySelector("[id ^= 'Buttons1_']").id.replace("Buttons1_rte", "");

    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "hidden";
    input.id = "hdndata[content1_html]_" + id;
    input.value = value;
    input.name = "data[content1_html]";

    parent.appendChild(input);
}, value);
```

I assume that the second `.rteDiv` is the one that you want to use, since the other one is the demo.

Comment: Is the "selector" variable equal to "input[id ^= 'hdndata[content1_html]']" ?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can try them out.

Comment: It times out and gives exiting error message. In addition, I have checked with the selector, it seems it does not find the input field with the selector specified.

Comment: Have you registered the event handlers to see if there are errors? Have you taken a screenshot to see if the page looks different for PhantomJS? Have you printed `casper.getHTML()` to see if the markup resembles what Firebug shows? Have you tried another PhantomJS version? Have you tried SlimerJS? You have to do some work.

Comment: Error: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('mainBanner').innerHTML = ''')
Error: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("chkSrcrte"+varEditor[t]).checked')
ResourceError: {
    "errorCode": 5,
    "errorString": "Operation canceled",
    "id": 11,
    "status": null,
    "statusText": null
In addition, it stuck at getting screenshot. I tried casper.getHTML() but I didn't find hidden colorless input field like the one I get in firebug. I got the same content as view page source.

Comment: Furthermore, I can post with filling the title field successfully. The only problem is filling this field. It cannot be fetched by the selector because it does not exist in the DOM.

Comment: I don't know what this colorless input field is called and why it is the way it is. Why is not it like the other input fields? Is it due to Javascript?

Comment: It's colorless, because it's a hidden field. What PhantomJS version do you have? You can try updating to PhantomJS 1.9.8 or 2.0.0 or running CasperJS with the commandline options `--ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true`. If nothing works, you can simply append that hidden field to the DOM and submit the form.

Comment: I have PhantomJs version 2.0.0 and CasperJs version 1.1.0-beta3. How can I add that hidden field to the DOM? I banging my head against the wall. I googled alot and finally led to StackOverflow. After spending hours, it has been inconclusive for me.

Comment: There are some questions that you have to answer if you want to add this input element yourself. Is there only one `.rteDiv`? Is the number 298996 dynamic (does it change when you open the page again)?

Comment: There two of .rteDiv in the page. One is for Demo post part and the other one is for further reading part. And the number you've mentioned is dynamic. In addition, form id and another hidden parameter are all dynamic.

Comment: As you have addressed I used those command line options, but again I get the error that the page I want to load - returns status = failed. I investigated further and found out Error opening url "undefined": undefined | But I am wondering even though I get this error I can submit the form without that hidden field and get result to be successful.

Comment: That was probably an unrelated ad script that couldn't be loaded. I'm not sure what can be done further.

Comment: I think PhantomJs has still lots of rooms for improvements and is full of various bugs. It takes time till its API becomes richer and much more responsive than the thing it already is. Don't you have any idea about adding the input to the DOM?

Comment: Adding something to the DOM is easy, but I don't know if it will help you. I extended my answer with an example.