# How can I select Javascript generated field in Jquery and PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, phantomjs

I want to how I can select a Javascript generated input field via Jquery.
For instance consider

```
<input type="hidden" name="field1_html" />
```

This input tag cannot be seen via view page source, it will only be shown in firebug or inspect element. It means that it only exists when the Javascript is generated. I know that for HTML DOM we can use CSS selectors in Jquery to select the elements we want from the DOM but as I said, I am looking for a way to select the elements which are only shown after the page is loaded. I have seen no resource on the way to fetch the fields which are generated by PhantomJS headless browser not the pure source which can be shown by `getHTML()` or `debugHTML()`. 
The above input tag is for instance generated by calling the Javascript function

```
geteditorinit("http://example.com/pub","data[content_html]",298996,1,750,350,0,0,"content_html");
```

How can I select the element generated by this Javascript function in PhantomJS?

Comment: Your long winded paragraphs are really hard to read. It seems that what you're asking I already answered in the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433842/load-the-javascript-of-the-page-while-loading-the-page-itself-with-casperjs). If it's not there it cannot be selected.

Comment: @ArtjomB. It is not answered over there. How can you say that you have the answered this question over there? I made another topic to have the question changed a little. How can you be so sure that there is no other way? That topic still holds to be completely inconclusive. Nothing has been solved in that topic yet.

Comment: If it is not possible at all, how does firebug show the Javascript rendered HTML?

Comment: As I see it, you're asking in this question how to select the given element using a jQuery selector. Since jQuery selectors are a superset of CSS selectors, this question is answered, because I've given you two selectors in the previous question.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Check the title, it also asks for a way in the PhantomJS

Comment: It's the same thing. Change `casper.evaluate()` for `page.evaluate()`.

Comment: maybe [Jquery :eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) will work, you'll need the index tho.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I am already using Casper. I have set value to the other input fields via `fill()` How can I select that hidden input produced by Javascript through evaluate? It should be possible, if it is not, how the browser itself runs javascript then? For instance, in firefox I can simply submit the form I have been struggling in 10 seconds.

Comment: It's obviously a limitation of PhantomJS. Perhaps the site does something funny like using flash or an experimental web API. I don't know. The viewport size might be the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the evaluate method to retrieve DOM info from the page.

For example:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://youpage.com', function(status) {

  var interv,
      tryToGetValue = function () {

          var v = page.evaluate(function() {
              return $("input[name='field1_html']").val();
          });

          if (v) {
               console.log('Value found: ', v);
               clearInterval(interv);
               phantom.exit();
          }

      };

      interv = setInterval(tryToGetValue, 300);

});
```

As you are willing to get a input which is generate by javascript, you may need to listen to some events like `onInitialized`, `onLoadFinished` or even use a setTimeout.

You can check for examples at the PhantomJS WebPage API docs
http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/

Comment: It returns null. It fails to fetch the input.

Comment: As I said, you may listen to a `onInitialized`, `onLoadFinished` webpage event, or even use periodic `setInterval` or `setTimeout` until the element is available. I'll edit with a `setInterval` example